# Which version of the PX4 software stack is compatible with ROS Noetic

Tags: gazebo, catkin-make, ros-noetic, compilation, px4

I cloned the source code of [PX4-Autopilot](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot) into my `ros_noetic_ws` and attempted to compile it using the `catkin_make` command, but the code is not compiling. Which version of [PX4-Autopilot](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot) is compatible with ROS Noetic?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! It seems that package is upgraded to ROS 2. However, I found [this documentation](https://docs.px4.io/main/en/ros/mavros_installation.html) that supports ROS Noetic.

Comment: I go through it. it is for ros melodic

Comment: It clearly mentions `noetic`. Please pay attention and try again

Comment: Got it, Thank you